# Get json data to $router.push in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, axios

im new on js, and i try to create a router from my backend `/user-info` where are stored all informations from the current user :

[image]

Now, i wanted to find a mean to handle each information to use that on my Vuejs `Dashboard`, i used `axios` for that, so this is what i made for `index.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { ensureAuth, ensureGuest } = require('../middleware/auth')
const axios = require('axios')


router.get('/user-info', ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {
   try {
     let uri = 'http://localhost:5000/user-info';
     res.json(`userInfo : ${req.user}`);
     this.axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
     this.$router.push({name:'Dashboard'});

   } catch (err) {
     console.error(err)
     res.render('error')
    }
 })
```

...and what i did for my `Dashboard.vue` :

```
<template>
  <div class="customers container">
  <h1 class="page-header">Welcome to your dashboard</h1>
  <table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>{{user.image}}</td>
     <td>{{'Hello' user.displayName}}</td>
     <<td>{{user.email}}</td>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
 </table>

</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
name: 'dashboard',
data () {
return {
    user: [],

  }
},

methods: {
getUserInfo(){
  this.$http.get('http:localhost:5000/user-info')
    .then(function(response){

    this.user = (response.body); 
   });
  }
 </script>
```

Unfortunately i got nodemon :

`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

Comment: You seem to be mixing up your backend and frontend code. Your Express code does not have `this.axios`, `this.$router` or anything at all to do with Vue

Comment: @Phil If I can't use `this.axios` & `this.$router` how am I going to link my frontend & backend ?

Comment: You're confusing Vue Router with Express Router. Vue Router is a client side router. Express Router is intended to run server side.

Comment: @tony19 can i use`${req.user}`  on front Vue ?

Comment: That question doesn't make much sense. `req` is an argument seen in Express's route handler. The front end sends the `user` data, and Express receives it in `req.user`.